# awk escape single quote

Tags: ubuntu, awk

Lets assume the following:

`head delete.txt | awk '{printf("curl -XPOST 'localhost:52000/buildings/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { '\'"query'\'": { '\'"match'\'": { '\'"building.id'\'" : '\'"%s'\'"} } } '; \n", $1);}'`

where the contains some strings and the double quotes have been escaped (") in order to be printed. What about the single quotes .

error message is awk:         ^ unterminated string

Comment: What a strange command line. I would used `xargs printf`.

Answer (score 0):

> What about the single quotes .

I saw typically it's used as a variable.

```
awk -v q="'" 'BEGIN {print q "Something" q}' </dev/null
```

But in your case, I would drop awk and if you meant to execute the `curl`:

```
head delete.txt | xargs -d '\n' -I {} curl -XPOST 'localhost:52000/buildings/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "query": { "match": { "building.id" :  "{}" }}'
```

or similar with `printf` when only for formatting.